# For what values of $c$ will $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{c}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1}\right)$ converge? (verify solution)

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

For what values of $c$ will $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{c}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1}\right)$$ converge?

The $n$th partial sum is given by:

\begin{align*}s_n&=c+\frac{c-1}{2}+\frac{c-1}{3}+ ... + \frac{c-1}{n-1} - \frac{1}{n} 
\\ &=c + (c-1)\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+...+\frac{1}{n-1}\right)-\frac{1}{n}
\\ & =c + (c-1)\left(\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}\right)-\frac{1}{n}.\end{align*}

Since a constant multiple of a divergent series is a divergent series, the term $(c-1)(\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n})$ (and thus the series) will diverge $\iff$ $c \neq 1$.

---

Comment: Looks right to me.

Comment: How did you go from the finite sum to the infinite one when dealing with $s_n$? I would just use $$
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^N {\left( {\frac{c}{n} - \frac{1}{{n + 1}}} \right)}  = (c - 1)\sum\limits_{n = 1}^N {\frac{1}{n}}  + \sum\limits_{n = 1}^N {\frac{1}{{n(n + 1)}}} .
$$

Comment: I hope I could make light on your question. :+)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might pave the way differently. We know that if $p>1$ and $$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}n^pu_n<\infty$$ then $\sum u_n$ converges. This, for the question, is equivalent to have $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{p-1}(c-1)<\infty$, so it should be $c=1$ if we are looking for the convergence!